# Combinatory Categorial Grammar style

Tags: grammar

i was looking arround here for this style of Categorial Grammar (see picture). However, i just find another types of notation, like the Prawtiz's style derivation. I want this style (some people call it Steedman sytle). If you can help with the package I must use and doing as example this derivation, i'll appreciate it.

[image: Getzen style]

Thanks

Comment: I think the best source for styles for this are Jason Baldridge's styles which can be found here on GitHub: https://github.com/jasonbaldridge/cg-latex

Comment: If you find the styles useful then I would recommend making a small sample document with them and posting it and the link as an answer to your own question. This way if others come across your question it will have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can obviously use a bit of improvement in terms of fine tuning horizontal placement, but I mainly present it to highlight some new capability of `tabstackengine 2018/03/05 (V2.10)` uploaded this past Monday, with `\TABrule`s and `\TABcline{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\tbs{\,\textbackslash}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\RR{%
  \rlap{\kern.5\dimexpr\tabbed@gap\relax\llap{\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{white}{$>$}}}}
\newcommand\LL{%
  \rlap{\kern.5\dimexpr\tabbed@gap\relax\llap{\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{white}{$<$}}}}
\makeatother
\setlength\TABruleshift{\dimexpr.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\TABstackTextstyle{\itshape}
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
\catcode`!=\active \def!{\upshape}
\catcode`?=\active \def?#1{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}
\tabbedShortstack{
!Female &        &!astronaut &  & !sets        &        & !new   &        & !record   &\\
\TABcline{1,3,5,7,9}
N/N     &        & N         &  &{!(}S\tbs NP\/{!)}/NP& & N/N    &        & N         &\\
\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule\RR&  &              &        &\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule\RR&\\
        &?N      &           &  &              &        &        &?N      &           &\\
\TABcline{1-3,7-9}
        &?{NP}   &           &  &              &        &        &?{NP}   &           &\\
        &        &           &  &\TABrule      &\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule\RR&\\
        &        &           &  &              &?{S\tbs NP}&     &        &           &\\
\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule   &\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule\LL&        &\\
        &        &           &?S&              &        &        &        &           &
}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was recently in need of this style of notation as well. To make it easier for others to get started using it, I am just combining the comment of [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318614/combinatory-categorial-grammar-style#comment778217_318614) and the answer by [yannis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418886/229576).

Indeed the best way to produce derivations of the Steedman style is to use the .sty files provided by [github.com/jasonbaldridge/cg-latex](http://github.com/jasonbaldridge/cg-latex). Simply copy them into your working directory, and then use this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ccg}
\usepackage{amstext}

\begin{document}

\deriv{5} {
    \text{Female}   & \text{astronaut}   & \text{sets}          & \text{new}  & \text{record}   \\
    \uline{1}       & \uline{1}          & \uline{1}            & \uline{1}   & \uline{1}       \\
    \text{N/N}      & \text{N}           & \text{(S\bs NP)/NP}  & \text{N/N}  & \text{N}        \\
                \fapply{2}               &                      &         \fapply{2}            \\
            \mc{2}{\text{N}}             &                      &      \mc{2}{\text{N}}         \\
                \uline{2}                &                      &         \uline{2}             \\
            \mc{2}{\text{NP}}            &                      &      \mc{2}{\text{NP}}        \\
                    &                    &                      \fapply{3}                      \\
                    &                    &                   \mc{3}{\text{S\bs NP}}             \\
                                    \bapply{4}                                &                 \\
                                 \mc{4}{\text{S}}                             &                 \\
}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: Combinatory Categorial Grammar example]

For the documentation you can refer to the Readme in the repository or, much easier, the manual by [yannis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18645/yannis) which has since moved to [here](https://www.imt-atlantique.fr/sites/default/files/users/user1063/ccg-manual.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. And welcome to TeX.se!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a draft of CCG style manual. It only covers categorial grammar derivations but it may spare some time to potential users. The PDF is [here](http://perso.telecom-bretagne.eu/yannisharalambous/data/ccg-manual.pdf)

Comment: Besides the manual, also a pointer to the macros would be useful.