# Complex dependency graph

Tags: linguistics

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Word1 word2 word3.

\end{document}
```

Is the following dependency graph ([from this website](http://corpus.quran.com/documentation/dependencygraph.jsp)) likely to be made via some LaTeX package? (The `tikz` package has a `dependency` package but it does not seem to be suitable for this job.) (Sadly, all the contacts listed in website seem to be long gone.)

[image]

Comment: https://ctan.org/topic/linguistic

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are not really on-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it or, if applicable, ask on [Software Recommendations SX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't think this is an ill-defined question. It asks quite specifically whether there is a package which enables a **particular** form of diagram to be drawn. If this were a question directed at some more maths or physicy diagram ("how do I draw Feinman diagrams in LaTeX") it would get answered. The fact that there are fewer people here who know about linguistics is no reason to close it. Someone might well be able to help, or to say "no, you will have to roll your own, and here's how to do it".

Comment: I think it would help to reopen the question if you add a small document ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) to your question that shows the text and ask how to add the lines and arrows.

Comment: @Nicola Like this?

Comment: Do you have a published source for this kind of diagram? It would be helpful to know what you're trying to achieve. It's easy to annotate text in this way in an *ad hoc* manner, but to do it with some generality would require a better understanding of what the analysis is. For example, this looks similar to Combinatorial Grammar, for which there is a package (unfortunately not on CTAN): https://github.com/jasonbaldridge/cg-latex. See also [Combinatory Categorial Grammar style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318614/2693)

Comment: There is no package for comic sans. Comic sans is a work of the devil and was banned from LaTeX. (Hmm... maybe I should consider writing my thesis in comic sans, then.)

Comment: I was mistaken. Of course, there is a [package comicsans on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comicsans).

Comment: @Alan I've updated question slightly, and added a source.

Comment: @blackened It seems that the `tikz-dependency` package gets you 90% of the way, certainly much better than you could do by hand, so I would work out a minimal example using that package and ask about the specific issue you are having.

Comment: See tikz-dependency on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-dependency?lang=en

Comment: It is a simply beautiful example! Backtracking to the site, I could not find any material on the drawing of the graphs. The engine is written in Java, and is available, but I don't know enough to get it and find the code that draws the graphs. Many of the links are broken, unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building Quran Corpus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622632/building-quran-corpus)